# Filtering Unwanted Data Crawling

Tags: web-services, filter, web-crawler

I manage a few websites, and one of them is being harassed by a spider in the morning during business hours. Generally, Google Bots and such will crawl during off peak hours, but this one doesn't respect general courtesies. Further, it's being passed through a proxy, with all of the incoming IPs resolving to Russian IPs. (So I can't simply contact the creator.)

What's the usual form of filtering out unwanted spider traffic? I currently implemented logic that simply stops accepting connections from requests to the same website after a certain threshold, but I'm afraid that this will filter wanted traffic from busy customers. I've also heard of people checking the incoming useragent and filtering based on that, but in the case of malicious bots, they can simply provide a new useragent signature, right?

It's taken down my server a few times, and I had to temporarily change the customer's domain name, but this will be devastating for their SEO.

Comment: You'd probably get better answers on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for the suggestion. How do I do that? I've never moved questions around, but I know people have moved my questions around in the past before.

Comment: I've flagged your question for a moderator to move it to serverfault.

Comment: okay, thanks. I see that the question is closed. do I need to take any steps, or simply wait for a mod?

Comment: I guess you can ask the same question on server fault now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I currently implemented logic that simply stops accepting connections from requests to the same website after a certain threshold, but I'm afraid that this will filter wanted traffic from busy customers.

If your threshold is a number of requests per second, people aren't that quick.  Of course, the spider can be slowed down to get under the threshold.

> I've also heard of people checking the incoming useragent and filtering based on that, but in the case of malicious bots, they can simply provide a new useragent signature, right?

Right.  Since you're detecting this spider somehow, you can try checking the useragent.

You can also block the IP addresses of the Russian proxy, if that won't keep valid customers away.

Congratulations on having a website that interests Chinese hackers, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and I'm glad the Chinese/Russian hackers took an interest in one of my sites. I have noticed that most of the proxy IPs that I've been able to detect are coming from RIPE. (Which has IPs based in Europe.) Since all of my customers are in the states, I think it's a pretty safe to simply filter RIPE IPs. Do you know where I could find a list of RIPE IPs? (Prefix for what RIPE ips generally start with?)

Comment: @Sal: Your server logs would be the best place to look for the IP addresses to block.  At some point, you'll get them all unless the Chinese hackers want to crawl your site specifically.